# How to turn number strings in a list of dictionaries into integers using javascript?

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary, d3.js, crossfilter

I have the following list of dictionaries but the issue is that the value under quantity for each dictionary is currently a string. I'd like to use crossfilter on this list, but in order to do so, I need to convert this into an integer.

```
var data = [{
    date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 190,
    tip: 100,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: NaN,
    tip: 100,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z",
    quantity: "1",
    total: 300,
    tip: 200,
    type: "visa"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z",
    quantity: "1",
    total: NaN,
    tip: null,
    type: "cash"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:02:03Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 90,
    tip: 0,
    type: "tab"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z",
    quantity: "2",
    total: 200,
    tip: null,
    type: "cash"
}, {
    date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z",
    quantity: "1",
    total: 200,
    tip: 100,
    type: "visa"
}];
```

This is something around what I'd like to do.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.quantity = d.parseInt(d.quantity,10);
});
```

Comment: What advantage does the use of crossfilter have over a plain loop? You are working with json data so using native methods should be the fastest.

Comment: crossfilter? sounds like a Nike tennis shoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing your code:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.quantity = parseInt(d.quantity,10);
});
```

OR

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.quantity = +d.quantity;
});
```